# Unlock account present in genesis.json for sending ether

Tags: ethereum, geth

I want to sent ether from first account to another.
For this i need to unlock the account.
For unlocking the account i need password, which i don't know.

https://github.com/Capgemini-AIE/ethereum-docker/tree/master/files
http://www.herongyang.com/Ethereum/Transfer-Fund-Send-Ether-from-One-Account-to-Another.html

Answer (score 0):

You can recover a wallet by providing:

- The private key
- The mnementics

If you don't have access to these informations then you can't do your operation